# Automatically redirect to login page when session timeout in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I'm working on Laravel 5.4. Without making a request pages must redirect to login page when session is timed out. I don't want any Javascript code. I tried but its not working well for multiple tabs.
I even tried with Middleware but that did not work.
References I tried :

- http://bmatovu.com/laravel-session-timeout-auto-logout/
- https://github.com/unicodeveloper/laravel-sessiontimeout/blob/master/src/Middleware/SessionTimeout.php

Is there any solution to solve this issue in Larvel 5.4 framework, directly redirect to login page after session timeout.

Comment: if the session has timed out and the user tries to reach something that has the `auth` middleware attached, they will get redirected to login ... not sure how you would force a browser to make a request to then have a redirect when the session expires on the server side though

Comment: You can't dynamically redirect the user when you are not checking if the user is still logged in. You will need some sort of JavaScript

Comment: You can also set a [meta](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) `refresh` tag in the page header with the remaining duration of the session if you want to avoid JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the 419 error in the render function of App\Exceptions\Handler.
Something like this

```
if (method_exists($exception, 'getStatusCode') && $exception->getStatusCode() == '419') {
    //your custom handler here
}
return parent::render($request, $exception);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
protected $middleware = [
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
        'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
        'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
        'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
        'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',// add this line according to your namespace if not found in your kernel.php
    ];
```

you just add your route in this middleware

```
Route::get('/admin-someting', ['middleware' => 'auth', function () {
    //your route
}]);
```

or this put on your controller

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```